# Separable polynomial definition (Confused)

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I understand there is a new and old definition of separable polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial).

For the following definition:

a) A polynomial over $F$ is said to be separable if it has no multiple roots. (given in Dummit & Foote)

b) a polynomial P(X) over a given field K is separable if its roots are distinct in an algebraic closure of K (Wikipedia)

c) A polynomial f in F[X] is a separable polynomial if and only if every irreducible factor of f in F[X] has distinct roots (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension#cite_note-6)

Question) Which is the correct definition?

I can see that (b) implies (c), for instance, but not sure if they are equivalent.

Thanks for help.

Comment: All of them are correct. They just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: (c) sounds like the "older definition" stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions are not equivalent. a) and b) is a stronger condition than c). The question is whether you want something like $x^2$ to be separable. For a),b) $x^2$ is not separable, for c) $x^2$ is separable, since its irreducible factors are separable.

Definition c) is in my opinion the better definition since it makes sure that a polynomial $f \in K[X]$ is separable if and only if the splitting field is a separable extension of $K$.

---

Furthermore, with definition c), you have that a field is perfect if and only if every polynomial over that field is separable.

With definitions a),b) you have to restrict to irreducible polynomials.

Comment: Thanks. Just to check, (a) is essentially the same as (b) right? I think for (a) Dummit and Foote, the roots are considered over the splitting field?

Comment: Yes, a) and b) are the same definitions.